# C# WPF button move with mouse

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a problem with moving the button, which is that it follows the button with the cursor, then when the left mouse button up it has a way to adjust to the correct position. Unfortunately, when I up the left button, the control does not improve its position, it just goes back to the previous position and when I point at it, it suddenly changes its position to a different one, and in this way it runs away.

XAML

```
    <Grid x:Name="GridMain" x:FieldModifier="public">

        <Button MouseLeftButtonDown="Button_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="Button_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="Button_MouseMove"></Button>
        <Button MouseLeftButtonDown="Button_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="Button_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="Button_MouseMove"></Button>
        <Button MouseLeftButtonDown="Button_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="Button_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="Button_MouseMove"></Button>
        <Button MouseLeftButtonDown="Button_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="Button_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="Button_MouseMove"></Button>
     </Grid>
```

C#

```
bool _isMoving;
System.Windows.Point? _buttonPosition;
System.Windows.Point relativePoint;
double deltaX;
double deltaY;
TranslateTransform _currentTT;
Button selectedButton;

    private void Button_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
                if (_buttonPosition == null && selectedButton = null)
               {
                _buttonPosition = this.TransformToAncestor(MainWindow.mainWindow.GridMain).Transform(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));
                selectedButton = (sender as Button);
               }

                var mousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(MainWindow.mainWindow.GridMain);
                deltaX = mousePosition.X - _buttonPosition.Value.X;
                deltaY = mousePosition.Y - _buttonPosition.Value.Y;
                _isMoving = true;
       }

        private void Button_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _isMoving = false;

            System.Windows.Point relativePoint = this.TransformToAncestor(MainWindow.mainWindow.GridMain).Transform(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));

            selectedButton.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(Math.Floor(relativePoint.X / 2), Math.Floor(relativePoint.Y / 45));
        }

        private void Button_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_isMoving) return;

            var mousePoint = Mouse.GetPosition(MainWindow.mainWindow.GridMain);

            var offsetX = (_currentTT == null ? _buttonPosition.Value.X : _buttonPosition.Value.X - _currentTT.X) + deltaX - mousePoint.X;
            var offsetY = (_currentTT == null ? _buttonPosition.Value.Y : _buttonPosition.Value.Y - _currentTT.Y) + deltaY - mousePoint.Y;

            selectedButton.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(-offsetX, -offsetY);
        }
```

Comment: Hi, you should post your xaml as well so we can know what mainWindow and GridMain are. I am also not sure how _buttonPosition and selectedButton are defined and how they are connected to the button you are trying to move.

Comment: I edited and mainWindow is reference to MainWindows.xaml.

Comment: You're already storing deltaX and deltaY; just use those values and the original button location to make your Transform.